# Segmented Iteration

Tags: php

I am using PHP Version 7.1.9 and what I am doing is returning some rows from a MySQL table, the return data looks like the following:

```
+-------------+-------+-------------+------------------+---------------------------+
| sequence_id | title | description | customer_type_id | customer_type_description |
+-------------+-------+-------------+------------------+---------------------------+
|      1      |  ...  |     ...     |        1         |          customer         |
|      2      |  ...  |     ...     |        1         |          customer         |
|      3      |  ...  |     ...     |        1         |          customer         |
|      4      |  ...  |     ...     |        2         |          prospect         |
|      5      |  ...  |     ...     |        3         |          winback          |
|      6      |  ...  |     ...     |        3         |          winback          |
|      7      |  ...  |     ...     |        4         |          business         |
+-------------+-------+-------------+------------------+---------------------------+
```

What I need to do is dynamically `<option>` elements for each of the rows, however, I also want to segment each option in an `<optgroup>` element based on the `customer_type_id` (or `customer_type_description`). So that the resulting DOM that gets created would look something like this:

```
<optgroup label="customer" data-customer-type-id="1">
  <option value="1" data-description="...">...</option>
  ...
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="prospect" data-customer-type-id="2">
  <option value="4" data-description="...">...</option>
</optgroup>
...
```

How could I segment my For/Each iteration to where I initially loop through each `customer_type_id` and inside that loop have a nested For/Each loop to iterate through each of the rows that match the id of the outer loop?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, if so show us

Comment: @RiggsFolly - No, I've sat around and drank coffee all day hoping that somebody would do the work for me without putting forth any effort. `</sarcasm>`

Comment: @RiggsFolly - If you'd care to see what I ultimately did (rather than just down vote for the sake of being a...), then look at the answer I provided.

Comment: Actually, just to keep the record straight, **I did not DownVote this question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while Syscall answered my question, I was hoping for something that wouldn't require a local variable solution. So, ultimately I was able to get the array_unique on array_values on array_column on the `customer_type_description`, then iterate through the results initially echo the `<optgroup>`, then use array filter on the initial collection querying for where the description matches the outer iteration, and finally echo the `<option>`.

Here is what I wound up using adapted to where I create a PHP array that illustrates what gets returned from the MySQL query:

```
$sequences = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'title' => '...', 'description' => '...', 'customer_type_id' => 1, 'customer_type_description' => 'customer'),
    array('id' => 2, 'title' => '...', 'description' => '...', 'customer_type_id' => 1, 'customer_type_description' => 'customer'),
    array('id' => 3, 'title' => '...', 'description' => '...', 'customer_type_id' => 1, 'customer_type_description' => 'customer'),
    array('id' => 4, 'title' => '...', 'description' => '...', 'customer_type_id' => 2, 'customer_type_description' => 'prospect'),
    array('id' => 5, 'title' => '...', 'description' => '...', 'customer_type_id' => 3, 'customer_type_description' => 'winback'),
    array('id' => 6, 'title' => '...', 'description' => '...', 'customer_type_id' => 3, 'customer_type_description' => 'winback'),
    array('id' => 7, 'title' => '...', 'description' => '...', 'customer_type_id' => 4, 'customer_type_description' => 'business'),
);

$unique_types = array_unique(array_values(array_column($sequences, 'customer_type_description')));
echo '<select>';
foreach($unique_types as $description) {
    echo '<optgroup label="' . $description . '">';
    foreach(array_filter($sequences, function($sequence) use ($description) {
            if ($sequence['customer_type_description'] == $description) {return $sequence;}
            }) as $sequence) {
        echo '<option value="' . $sequence['id'] . '" data-description="' . $sequence['description'] . '">' . $sequence['title'] . '</option>';
    };
    echo "</optgroup>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

And it outputs (formatted):

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="customer">
    <option value="1" data-description="...">...</option>
    <option value="2" data-description="...">...</option>
    <option value="3" data-description="...">...</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="prospect">
    <option value="4" data-description="...">...</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="winback">
    <option value="5" data-description="...">...</option>
    <option value="6" data-description="...">...</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="business">
    <option value="7" data-description="...">...</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to store a local variable that maintains the last ID. And then, check if the last is different than the current :

```
$last_customer_type_id = 0 ;
if (!empty($array)) {
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if ($last_customer_type_id != $item['customer_type_id']) {
            if ($last_customer_type_id != 0) {
                echo '</optgroup>' ;
            }
            $last_customer_type_id = $item['customer_type_id'] ;
            echo '<optgroup label="customer" data-customer-type-id="'.$item['customer_type_id'].'">' ;
        }
        echo '   <option value="'.$item['sequence_id'].'" data-description="...">...</option>' ;
    }
    echo '</optgroup>' ;
}
```

Outputs :

```
<optgroup label="customer" data-customer-type-id="1">
   <option value="1" data-description="...">...</option>
   <option value="2" data-description="...">...</option>
   <option value="3" data-description="...">...</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="customer" data-customer-type-id="2">
   <option value="4" data-description="...">...</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="customer" data-customer-type-id="3">
   <option value="5" data-description="...">...</option>
   <option value="6" data-description="...">...</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="customer" data-customer-type-id="4">
   <option value="7" data-description="...">...</option>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ouups ! Thank you. Just for my test :p Removed ! Thanks.

Comment: This is what I had in mind, I was just hoping that there would be something internally that would split up the array into segmented arrays so that I wouldn't need to keep track of anything outside the loop.